# How to decide if a separate entity and DAO is needed for an association table?

Tags: java, associations

How to decide if a separate entity and DAO is needed for an association table?

Suppose I have 3 tables: `user`, `role` and `user_role`. `user_role` is the association table.

```
create table user (user_id int not null primary key, login varchar(50) not null unique key, password varchar(100))
create table role (role_id int not null primary key, description varchar(100))
create table user_role (user_role_id int not null identity(1,1) primary key, user_id int not null foreign key references user(user_id), role_id int not null foreign key references role(role_id))
```

Now I will have separate entities and DAOs for `user` and `role` tables.

```
public class User {
   private int userId;
   private String login;
   private String password;
   // getters and setters
}
public interface UserDAO {
   User getUserById(int userId);
   void insertUser(User user);
   void updateUserById(User user);
   void deleteUserById(User user);
}

public class Role {
   private int roleId;
   private String description;
   // getters and setters
}
public interface RoleDAO {
   User getRoleById(int roleId);
   void insertRole(Role role);
   void updateRoleById(Role role);
   void deleteRoleById(Role role);
}
```

I will have 3 screens:

- **Screen 1:** I will have a screen to maintain CRUD operations on `user` table.
- **Screen 2:** I will have a screen to maintain CRUD operations on `role` table.
- **Screen 3:** I will have a screen where users will be assigned to roles.

But I am confused about how to tackle the `user_role` table.

**a)** Should `User` entity have a list of associated `Role`. And thats enough?

```
public class User {
   private int userId;
   private String login;
   private String password;
   private Set<Role> roles;
   // getters and setters
}
```

**b)** Should `Role` entity have a list of associated `User`. And thats enough?

```
public class Role {
   private int roleId;
   private String description;
   private Set<User> users;
   // getters and setters
}
```

**c)** Should I have a separate entity and DAO for `user_role` table like this:

```
public class UserRole {
   private int userRoleId;
   private User user;
   private Role role;
}
public interface UserRoleDAO {
   User getUserRoleById(int userRoleId);
   void insertUserRole(UserRole userRole);
   void updateUserRoleById(UserRole userRole);
   void deleteUserRoleById(UserRole userRole);
}
```

Comment: Consider having a reference to a `Role` object: Do you think you ever have to navigate from such a role object to the users that have this role (as part of your business logic)? If so, how often? In most cases, you don't. And this is the reason, why a `Set<User>` in the `Role` class is usually not needed.

Comment: Are you doing this all by hand? This seems the sort of thing where a join table would be ideal, and JPA(/Hibernate) makes it easy.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose you are right. I dont need `Set<User>` in `Role`. What about `UserRole`? Is it needed?

Comment: @chrylis yes I am doing all this by hand. Dont have real experience with JPA yet so dont know how to handle it with JPA. You think it would be better if I go towards JPA?

Comment: I strongly recommend not rolling your own DAOs by hand. JPA is the way to go if you're using a SQL database, and I personally use Spring Data repositories on top of my data stores (MongoDB right now).

Answer (score 0):

I guess as it a bidirectional relationship between user and roles you should have to have set of roles in User.java and set of users in Roles.java. An separate entity user_roles is definitely required. If you have dao for user you can have below methods in userdao

```
 User getUserRoleById(int userRoleId);
 void insertUserRole(UserRole userRole);
 void updateUserRoleById(UserRole userRole);
 void deleteUserRoleById(UserRole userRole);
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is a bidirectional relationship. I most likely will never need to display the users which belong to a role. But when I am deleting a role I would need to first check if there are associated users to that role (in `user_role` table); if there are associated users then I would need to give an error message that there are users associated to this role so this role cannot be deleted.